# How to name elements in a matrix in mathematica

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

I have thousands of vectors that represent waveforms, each of those waveforms is representative of a particular sample.  I would like to be able to perform an operation on each of those samples and have the output associated with the name of that sample.  I have found some information about keys in Mathematica but I can't get them to work correctly.  A very simplified example is below.  Suppose I have three vectors with 5 elements in each.  I could represent this as a matrix in Mathematica as follows:

```
InputSamples={{1,3,5,6,8}->"SampleA",{7,9,10,45,20}->"SampleB",{90,43,2,1,0}->"SampleC"};
```

Now suppose I want to do some calculation on each of the samples.

I might choose:

```
Map[Total,InputSamples]
```

Now I would want my output to be:

```
{{SampleA,23},{SampleB,91},{SampleC,136}}
```

But instead I get:

```
{{1+SampleA,3+SampleA,5+SampleA,6+SampleA,8+SampleA},{7+SampleB,9+SampleB,10+SampleB,45+SampleB,20+SampleB},{90+SampleC,43+SampleC,2+SampleC,1+SampleC,0+SampleC}}
```

How can I get this to give the output shown above that I would like or something similar to it?

Comment: Store your raw data in an association ([`Association`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Association.html)) like `InputSamples = <| "SampleA" -> {1,3,5,6,8}, "SampleB" -> ...|>` and then make efficient use of [functions related to `Association`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/guide/Associations.html) to manipulate it,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You get what you ask for with this

```
InputSamples={{1,3,5,6,8}->"SampleA",{7,9,10,45,20}->"SampleB",{90,43,2,1,0}->"SampleC"};
Map[{#[[2]],Total[#[[1]]]}&,InputSamples]
```

which instantly returns

```
{{SampleA,23},{SampleB,91},{SampleC,136}}
```

Be careful with that and test this method before depending on it

It is not the usual "try to write everything as punctuation characters" style, but this

```
ruletotal[list_->name_]:={name,Total[list]};
Map[ruletotal,InputSamples]
```

accomplishes the same thing and might give you some ideas how to do similar tasks in the future.

Answer (score 1):

Some other options

```
MapAt[Total, InputSamples, {All, 1}]
(* {23 -> "SampleA", 91 -> "SampleB", 136 -> "SampleC"} *)

List @@@ MapAt[Total, InputSamples, {All, 1}]
(* {{23, "SampleA"}, {91, "SampleB"}, {136, "SampleC"}} *)

InputSamples // Association // KeyMap[Total]
(* <|23 -> "SampleA", 91 -> "SampleB", 136 -> "SampleC"|> *)

InputSamples // Association // KeyMap[Total] // AssociationMap[Reverse]
(* <|"SampleA" -> 23, "SampleB" -> 91, "SampleC" -> 136|> *)
```